# Let $x$ be in the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ and let $f(x)=|2x-1|-3|2x+4|+7$ be a function, write $f(x)$ without the absolute value.

Tags: functions, absolute-value

Let $x$ be in the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ and let $f(x)=|2x-1|-3|2x+4|+7$ be a function, write $f(x)$ without the absolute value.

I thought of it this way: $$f(x)=\begin{cases}2x-1-3(2x+4)+7 \,(\text{then I simplify)} & \text{if $x>0$}\\
-(2x-1-3(2x+4)+7)\,(\text{then I simplify)} & \text{if $x\le0$}\end{cases}$$

But is there some way without having to use the cases?

Edit: NEW work on this problem! I found three cases;

If $x\in ]-\infty,-2]$ then f(x)=$4x+20$

If $x\in]-2,1/2]$ then f(x)=$-8x-4$

If $x\in]1/2,+\infty[$ then f(x)=$-4x-6$

**IS THIS TRUE?**

Thank you very much!

Comment: This is not correct. When is 2x-1 positive or negative? And the same question about 2x+4. It has nothing to do with $x>0$ and $x<0$.

Comment: So how can I do it??

Comment: Imagine you have only $f(x)=|2x-1|$. Try graphing it online or even better by yourself. The critical point is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Each of the absolute value expressions has different regions where you can 'simplify' them. You need to find all of them (In general, in an expression with 2 abs. values, there will be 4 regions: both positive, first pos. second neg, first neg. second pos, both negative.)

Comment: So even if I do that I'll have to make a function defined by cases ?

Comment: Yes, you cannot avoid cases. If you want to avoid cases, use absolute value :)

Comment: please check my answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/615628/117228

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a start. You need to consider different cases.

**Case 1:** $2x-1\geq 0  \cap  2x+4 \geq 0 \implies x\geq \frac{1}{2} $. For this case, we have

> $$ f(x) = (2x-1)-3(2x+4)+7=-4x -6 .$$

**Case 2:** $2x-1 < 0  \cap  2x+4 < 0 \implies x<-2$ which gives

> $$ f(x) = -(2x-1)-3(-(2x+4))+7=4x + 20. $$

Now, I leave it for you to discover the other possible cases.

Comment: Please check my answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/615628/117228

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!! Then how can I use it to solve the equation $f(x)=0$

Comment: Make sure of the interval in your second case . It should be open at $1/2$ and closed at $-2$.

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean?

Comment: It should be $[-2,1/2)$.

Comment: For the third case it should be $[1/2, \infty) $.

Comment: Okay but how can I use my result to prove that $f(x)=0$

Comment: Maybe you have been asked to solve  for $x$, by setting $f(x)=0$. So, in this case you have three different equations , set them equals zero and solve for $x$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$x=\frac{1}{2}$ & $x=-2$ are the critical points. You need to check function in following intervals $(-\infty,-2),(-2,1/2),(1/2,+\infty)$

Comment: Do you mean $]-\infty,-2]$ or $]-\infty,-2[$

Comment: $(-\infty,-2)$ because for $x=-2,f(-2)=|2(-2)-1|+3|2(-2)+4|+7|=12$

Comment: Adil, please see my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/615628/117228

Answer (score 2):

Let f(x)=|x|.We know $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
-x \text{  if x<0}\\
x\text{ if x>0}
\end{cases}$$

What if f(x)=|x-1|. We must have,
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
-(x-1) \text{  if x<1}\\
x-1\text{ if x>1}
\end{cases}$$

Note that there are 3 terms in the given function.
$|2x-1|$, $3|2x+4|$ and 7.

The first term is postive if x$\gt \frac{1}{2}$. The second term is positive if $x\gt -2$. Hence we must have,
$$f(x)=2x-1-3(2x+4)+7 \text{   whenever   x$\gt \frac{1}{2}$}$$
The first term is negative if x$\lt \frac{1}{2}$ and the second term is negative if x$\lt -2$.Hence we have a second condition,
$$f(x)=-(2x-1)+3(2x+4)+7 \text{   whenever   x$\lt -2$}$$
Can you work out what will happen if x $\in (-2,\frac{1}{2})$?

---

> ! If x $\in (-2,\frac{1}{2})$ surely |2x-1|<0,hence |2x-1|=-(2x-1) and |2x+4|>0,hence |2x+4|=2x+4.
>   Finally we have the following for f(x)
>   $$f(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> 2x-1-3(2x+4)+7~ \text{, x$\gt \frac{1}{2}$}\\
> -(2x-1)+3(2x+4)+7~ \text{, x$\lt -2$}\\
> -(2x-1)-3(2x+4)+7 ~\text{, x$\in(-2,\frac{1}{2})$}
> \end{cases}
> $$

Comment: No :( I don't know

Comment: Did you understand this: if
f(x)=|x|.We know $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
-x \text{  if x<0}\\
x\text{ if x>0}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Please check my answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/615628/117228

Comment: So is it:

I found three cases;
<br>
If $x\in ]-\infty,-2]$ then f(x)=$4x+20$
<br>
If $x\in]-2,1/2]$ then f(x)=$-8x-4$ 
<br>
If $x\in]1/2,+\infty[$ then f(x)=$-4x-6$
<br>
**IS THIS TRUE?**

Comment: Yes. It is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The absolute value has a discontinuous slope change at zero. Hence, f(x) has discontinuous slope changes at -2 from $|2x+4|$ and at 1/2 from $|2x-1|$. So there are three cases: $-\infty < x \le -2$, $-2 < x \le 1/2 $ and $1/2 < x < \infty$.

Now for $x$ sufficiently negative $|2x+4| = -2x-4$ and we know that $|2x+4|$ had discontinuous slope at $2x+4=0$. Similarly for sufficiently negative $x$ $|2x-1| = -2x+1$ and changes slope when $2x-1=0$. Hence

$$
f(x) = \left{ 
 \begin{array}{ll}
    +3(2x+4)-(2x-1)+7, & x  \le -2; \\
    -3(2x+4) -(2x-1)+7, & -2 <x \le 1/2; \\
   -3(2x+4)+(2x-1)+7, & 1/2 < x
\right.
$$

Sorry! Don't see why the formatting is messed up. Hope it makes sense!  I tried to use plain vanilla latex commands. I need to learn MathJaX